# GWT/GWTP PopupDialog not always centered due to CSS delayed rendering

Tags: css, gwt, centering, gwt-platform, gwtp

I am using GWT 2.4, GWTP and Chrome 22.0.1229.94 for testing. I have struggled with this issue for days.

On startup I present a custom PopupDialog using a view that has extended PopupViewImpl. In an overridden onReveal() method I center the dialog. The GWTP code centers synchronously and also using scheduleDeferred.

In development mode and running complied on local server everything works as expected: the popup dialog is always rendered and centered correctly. I have also tested in IE.

However, when deploying to the live web server on the Internet I notice that when I refresh using F5, sometimes the CSS is not applied before the script tries to center the dialog. This results in the measurements being wrong and the dialog is not placed in the center. Interestingly this only seems to happen now and then, typically when the browser is not fast enough in rendering all (CSS) resources before the scheduled deferred command is invoked.

So, I have already tried the following:

1. Loading CSS using different techniques (reference in HTML-file, reference in GWT-module, put in CssResouce)
2. Center using Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred as default code also does.
3. Calling RootLayoutPanel.get().onResize() in onReveal to try to trigger some layout before centering deferred.

I notice the same behaviour in Chrome and IE so it might not be a browser issue. My question is where to put my "center"-call to ensure that it is called after the all CSS has been properly applied or if there is anything else I can do to force the CSS to render?

Thanks!

Here is the onReveal code in the Presenter extending PresenterWidget:

```
@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();

    // Hide loading image
    fireEvent(new HideApplicationLoadingImageEvent());

    // Reset message
    getView().setStatusMessage(null);

    // Center the popup
    getView().center();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your onReveal() code which applies to centering the dialog?

Comment: Added onReveal code in post above.

Answer (score 0):

There is method addToPopupSlot(child, boolean center); if you send true for center argument it take care of centering the popup in GWTP Example:- addToPopupSlot(widget, true)